# Not able to use OR in where clause with CaminteJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question regarding OR operation in where clause.
I am using cross-platform ORM CaminteJS to perform an operation on mysql and mongoDB.
I want to write a ORM query like "Select * from users where username = 'asd' OR email = 'asd@gmail.com' ". I am not able to write this, neither i am getting any errors.

Need Help

```
Users.findOne(
    {
        where: {
            or: [
                { username: req.params.username },
                { mobile: req.params.mobile }
            ]
        }
    }, function (err, user) {
        if(user) {
            done(user, null);
        } else {
            done(null, err);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the CaminteJS query structure for or would be like this:

```
Users.findOne(
{
    where: { 
        username: req.params.username,
        or: [{ mobile: req.params.mobile }]
    }
}, function (err, user) {
    if(user) {
        done(user, null);
    } else {
        done(null, err);
    }
});
```